# Why does the presence of after_create_commit make my after_update_commit never fire?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm seeing a scenario where i have something like this:

```
class User
  def thing; puts "hello"; end
  after_update_commit :thing
  after_create_commit :thing
end
```

the `after_update_commit` never fires when doing `user.update first_name: rand`
but if i comment out `after_create_commit`, it does work.

- Whichever one is declared last is the one that wins.
- seems to only be for _commit callbacks
- only happens with multiple callbacks for same method

Is this a Rails bug or is there a reason for this?

rails 6.1.4.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#transaction-callbacks

> Using both after_create_commit and after_update_commit with the same method name will only allow the last callback defined to take effect, as they both internally alias to after_commit which overrides previously defined callbacks with the same method name.

solution if don't have conditions:

```
after_commit :thing, on: [:update, :create]
```

solution if do have condition (in this case, `is_active?` on update)

```
after_commit :thing, on: [:update, :create]

def thing
  # id_previously_changed? is only true when record is created
  unless id_previously_changed?
    return unless is_active?
  end

# ...
end
```

Comment: i blogged: https://code.jjb.cc/you-can-t-declare-after_-_commit-or-after_commit-callbacks-for-the-same-method-more-than-once

Answer (score 2):

As it was said in John Bachir answer you may have different conditions for `create` and for `update` actions (and these conditions may be complicated). I ended up with:

```
class User
  def thing; puts "hello"; end
  after_commit :thing_on_create, on: :create, if: :create_condition?
  after_commit :thing_on_update, on: :update, if: :update_condition?

  alias_method :thing_on_create, :thing
  alias_method :thing_on_update, :thing

  def create_condition?
    Time.now.monday?
  end

  def update_condition?
    active?
  end
end
```

It is a little bit more readable (and does not affect the method itself) IMO.